# Codeigniter : Join 2 tables based on where condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have to select data from two tables for APIs.

There are two tables garage_services, and garages. I receive **garage_sevices** id.

**Garage_services** table is like this

```
id | garage_id | service _id
```

Now from this table I select row based on service_id  from here I have to select garage_id and get details about garage from garage table

```
$garages = $this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('garage_services')
    ->join('garage', 'garage_services.id=garage.id')
    ->where($where)
    ->get();
```

Above is the query I came up with, I don't know if its correct.  as I am not sure about $where as well.

Please help me with this

Comment: Please provide your 2 table details

Comment: from garage table i just have to match the id of  garage with the table mentioned above . id from garage table should be equel to garage_id from the table mentioned above

Comment: You are receiving the garage_service_id as your function argument right?

Comment: Actually your details is not more clear if you are not getting the result just provide us the 2 table details and also what you want to get the result. We will do for you.

Comment: @Sikander have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Here I have written the query for your solution.**

```
$garages = $this->db->from('garage_services as gs, garages as g')
                    ->where('g.id', $garage_service_id, FALSE)
                    ->get();
```

Here `$garage_service_id` is the variable that passed in function argument as you have written you in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
->select('*')
     ->from('garage_services as t1')
     ->join('garage as t2', 't1.garage_id = t2.id')
     ->where('t1.id', $service _id)
     ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the detail is given in the question your query look correct and for the where condition:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table1.col1 = table2.col1');
$this->db->where('table1.col1', 2);

$query = $this->db->get();
```